# kontakt.io sdk does not work in killed state

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-location, ibeacon

I am using a kontakt SDK for beacon identification. I have a three beacon of kontakt and each one having a same UUID but major and minor number is different. It will work fine in all state except terminated state.

My Question:

Is it identify the beacons in terminated state or not?
if yes then please tell me the procedure.

I am using this tutorial http://docs.kontakt.io/ios-sdk/quickstart/#beacon-bluetooth-management for implementation purpose.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If im not wrong, you need the background permission mode "bluetooth-central" to do that.

More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

If you already have it then i think theres no more you can do.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Nanoc, i am not adding this in my project but i will try this one, but this one for background processing as per my perception. My problem is how to identify a beacon at the time when application is in terminated state.

Comment: I should be the same as having the app in foreground, IOS should wake your app and call your delegate when entering beacon region.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your opinion, but this will not happen. have you ever work on this type of applications?

Comment: -locationManager:locationManager:didEnterRegion,
-locationManager:locationManager didExitRegion these are two delegate methods, but they are also not called.

Comment: worked with kontakt and estimote mainly but never used their sdk, always IOS native library, as far as i know, your app should wake up, but i really never tried it.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will used iOS native library and  try to solved my problem.